# cin.get() not functioning as desired

Tags: c++, input, blocking, cin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Program not waiting for cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272277/program-not-waiting-for-cin)

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void search(int pre, int a, int b, int x) {
    char c;
    cout << "Is the number " << ((x == 2) ? b : a) << endl;
    c = cin.get(); ////// this does not block
    if (c == 'y') return;

    else {
        cout << "Is the number " << ((x == 2) ? b : a) << " closer to your number than " << pre;
        c = cin.get();

        if (c == 'y') {
            search(a, a, (a + b) / 2, 2);
        } //c=='y'
        else search(a, (a + b) / 2, b, 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    int N;
    cout << "Enter N? ";
    cin >> N;

    search(N, 1, N, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

No need to worry if you don't understand the logic because my question is not regarding that.

In the search function, there are two cin.get(), where i need the user to enter a character. My problem is that the the program blocks for input only after the second cin.get().

For example:

```
 Is the number 7  //program doesn't wait after this
 Is the number 7 closer to your number than 8  //program blocks here for an input
```

Why does it do so?

Comment: The problem is in the code you didn't show. Write a simple program that **just** calls this function. It will work just fine. Then start changing that simple program, adding in the things your current program does now, until the problem reappears. Then think about what you changed.

Comment: this is a common "issue", search for "cin get flush" on this site...

Comment: The problem is the lack of something after the `cin >>` in main. Try calling the function twice and the first `get` should work just fine the second time.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer

Comment: @chris Or not.  He has to define exactly what he should extract after `std::cin >> N`.

Comment: @PeteBecker..this is the entire code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two problems in your code.  The first is that you're
leaving characters in the buffer after inputting `N`.  The simplest
solution is to just add a call to `std::cin.ignore( INT_MAX, '\n' );`
after `std::cin >> N;`; a better solution (because it allows for more
error checking) would be to use `std::getline` to read the complete
line, then parse it using `std::istringstream`.

The second problem is that you're assigning the results of
`std::cin.get()` into a `char`.  `std::cin.get()` returns an `int`,
which may be `EOF`.  And you really want to check whether it is `EOF`
before converting the `int` to `char`: you cannot check after because
either some legal `char` will compare equal to `EOF` (plain `char` is
signed), or the `char` will never compare equal to `EOF` (plain `char`
is unsigned).  The other alternative is to do something like:

```
if ( !std::cin.get( c ) ) {
    //  EOF or error seen...
}
```

each time you want to read a `char`.  (This might be better in your
case, since if you do read `EOF`, all further calls to `std::cin.get()`
will return `EOF`.)