# Why is this "Press Enter to Continue" code in C++ not working?

Tags: c++, cout, cin, enter

So, I was making a simple quiz program for kids in C++ (I am really a beginner to programming). What I wanted to do was require the user to press Enter after the first question and only upon pressing enter, the second question is visible. But due to some reasons, C++ doesn't waits for the user to enter an output in the cin statement and automatically prints the next question.

Here's the code:

```
cout << "Q1. Which of these languages is not used to make Computer Software?" << endl;
cout << "a. Python" << endl;
cout << "b. Java" << endl;
cout << "c. C++" << endl;
cout << "d. HTML" << endl;
cout << "" << endl;
cin >> ans;
cout << "" << endl;
cout << "Press Enter to Continue";
cin.ignore();
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272277/program-not-waiting-for-cin

Comment: To hell with Enter, what's the correct answer?!!!

Comment: @bipll Check out both the answers below. They both are correct.

Comment: I don't see it. Which one? Python, Java, C++ or HTML? Now I can't sleep! I bet on Java!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have already entered "enter" after providing some data for `ans`. In that case, the `cin.ignore()` will read the "enter" and immediately return. Therefore, you would want another `cin.ignore()` for wait for another "enter".

Comment: Thanks alot. Works like a charm. But can you please explain me why did I had to enter cin.ignore(); twice? I couldn't get the explaination you have written above...

Comment: @SatyamSingh Related: [c++ - Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you have entered **Enter** after ans/input (with one word). So, when you press **Enter**, it takes **ans** string as input and treats the following newline as delimeter.
As a result, newline is not read and it remains in the input buffer which is automatically taken as next input. That is, **cin.ignore()** ignore this newline and control goes to the next instructions.

To fix it, use **cin.getline(ans)**/**getline(cin, ans)** instead of **cin** or use another **cin.ignore()** to ignore your next **Enter** ("Press Enter to Continue").